# Split play2-mini Routes in several files

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, play2-mini

I'm pretty new to the whole Scala and Play thing so maybe my way solving this is not the right one. I'm using Scala 2.9.1 and play-mini_2.9.1-2.0.1.

I have an App.scala which usually contains the routes. But my intention is not to insert all possible routes in this file but split it by entities. In my case: User, Role, Process.

To achieve this I tried something like that:

```
//in App.scala
object App extends Application { 
  println("Checking Database")
  ...      
  println("Resume executions from database")
  ...      
  def route = Routes(Process.routes :: User.routes) // I know this is wrong but I think you get what I want to do...
}

//in Process.scala
object Process {
  val routes = Routes(
    {
        case GET(Path("/process")) => Action{ request =>
            // returns a list of processes
        }
        case GET(Path("/process")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request =>  
            val id = QueryString(qs,"id").getOrElse(0)
            // return process by id
        } 
    }
  )
}

//in User.scala
object User { 
  val routes = Routes(
    {
        case GET(Path("/user")) => Action{ request =>
            // returns a list of processes
        }
        case GET(Path("/user")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request =>     
            val id = QueryString(qs,"id").getOrElse(0)
            // return process by id
        } 
    }
  )
}
```

This is just the first step. My final goal is to load all objects (process, user etc.) dynamically from a specified package. Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `orElse` to combine the routes:

```
val routes = User.routes orElse Process.routes
```

In fact using, the `Routes.apply` method that you invoke when you write `val routes = Routes(...)` will return a scala [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) which defines the method `orElse` used above.

Pay attention to the order, in my example the routes in `User.routes` will be tested for a match before the routes in `Process.routes`.